# Adding customized basemap ArcGIS vector tile to QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, arcgis-online-basemaps

I customized a basemap through the platform [ArcGIS Vector Tile Style Editor (beta)](https://developers.arcgis.com/vector-tile-style-editor/) and I would like to share it and use it also with other software like qgis.

I am using this link:
https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/15a61dd0045f40b0836dc73af2ed9d3d/resources/styles/root.json

Does somebody know if customized vector tile created in arcgis can be usually added to QGIS or other software?

What do I need to do?